# How to tell Jackson to make a sub-element the top level element

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I know how to *unwrap* an `Object` in Jackson but I can not find any examples on how to *unwrap* two layers.

Sharepoint API EndPoints return everything in the following format:

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
               /* lots objects with lots of properties 
                  that are irrelevant to the question */
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried the following and it does not make `results` value the top level object.

```
this.om.readerFor(new TypeReference<List<User>>() {})
       .withRootName("d")
       .readValue(response.parseAsString());
```

How do I tell `Jackson` to start parsing the the `results` as a top level `Array` **without having to create a custom object hierarchy** and **without having to write a custom deserializer**. I have a custom object that is annotated that this will populate, I want `TypeSafety` so `Map<String,Object>` is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the most efficient way, but can try to parse object as a tree first and then navigate to the node you need. Something like this:

```
mapper.readerFor(new TypeReference<List<User>>() {}).readValue(mapper.readTree(json).get("d").get("results"))‌​;
```

Easier to read:

```
mapper.convertValue(mapper.readTree(json).get("d").get("‌​results"), new TypeReference<List<User>>() {});
```

Comment: I came up with variation of this solution independently, I think it is the best way to get what I want.

Comment: As for *efficient*, it has to parse it all once anyway, so passing in the `JsonNode` to start converting is not less efficient in any meaningful way. This just does what it normally does but in two explicit stages. If it had to be super efficient in `space` or `time` I would not be using `Json` much less `SharePoint` :-)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson yeah, i also think that performance is not a big deal here. Actually i released that i never tested performance, always relying on others people words.  And after basic tests: https://gist.github.com/varren/3b7468a1d7abadad4958fe6bd7d42d44#file-main-java-L153-L178  From `time` point it doesn't look that bad, can be 2 times slower for simple cases with 1 field in user and probably 30% slower for complex json. From space point it is also almost 2 times less efficient https://i.stack.imgur.com/bftGe.png then wraper objects or custom deserilizer  or inline `JsonParser`

Answer (score 1):

```
@JsonRootName("d")
class Data {
    public Map<String, Object>[] results;
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);

Map<String, Object> results = new LinkedHashMap<>();
results.put("key1", "val1");
results.put("key2", "val2");

Data expected = new Data();
expected.results = new Map[1];
expected.results[0] = results;

String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(expected);
Data actual = mapper.readerFor(Data.class).readValue(json);
```

Json string looks like:

```
{
  "d" : {
    "results" : [ {
      "key1" : "val1",
      "key2" : "val2"
    } ]
  }
}
```

***P.S.*** In case of you do not care about concreate object and `Map<String, Object>` is OK for you, then you could use like this.

```
Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>)((List<?>)mapper.readerFor(Map.class).<Map<String, Map<String, ?>>>readValues(json).next().get("d").get("results")).get(0);
```

Comment: *"without having to create an object hierarchy"* - I do not want to have to have a special class for this as I stated in the question.

Comment: If you do not care about concrete object and Map<String, Object> is OK for you, then I think you could do like: Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>)((List<?>)mapper.readerFor(Map.class).<Map<String, Map<String, ?>>>readValues(json).next().get("d").get("results")).get(0);